# How do I block an IP address or network block with Varnish VCL?

Tags: ip, varnish, block

How does one block either IP address of network range inside of Varnish's VCL file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
acl unwanted {
    "69.60.116.0"/24;
    "69.90.119.207";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip ~ unwanted) {
        error 410;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: im using varnish version 4 and i got error this one when reloading vcl config: Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected an action, 'if', '{' or '}'
('input' Line 40 Pos 1)
error 410;
#####-----

Comment: Same her, trying to figure it out. Will report back

Comment: @risnandar this is version 3 syntax. Since version 4, there is a new one, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since Varnish 4, the syntax has changed!

**Instead of**:

```
error 403;
```

**you need to use**:

```
return(synth(403, "Access denied"));
```

Using *alexus*' example:

```
acl unwanted {
    "69.60.116.0"/24;
    "69.90.119.207";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (client.ip ~ unwanted) {
        return(synth(403, "Access denied"));
    }
}
```